# ubuntu-geoip-provider 100% cpu

Tags: 14.10, thinkpad, cpu-load, 15.04, geoip

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ubuntu-geoip-provider is using a full core on my laptop and doesn't seem like it'll ever finish up - have left it running for at least 30mins before killing it. it'll restart again at some point and be back to 100%

anything I can try to resolve this?  I was on a fresh install of 14.10 and had the same issue then, now upgraded to 15.04.

Comment: there seems to be a few ways to [turn it off](http://askubuntu.com/questions/142581/is-ubuntu-geoip-geoclue-used-for-tracking). I just kill it in `htop` whenever it spins up my cpu

Comment: thanks, unfortunately that link notes that removing geoclue means you have to update your clock manually and you lose the date/time display.  I'll keep looking for another solution.